# NSURLSession leak - downloadTaskWithRequest

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsurlsession

I just downloaded NSURLSession simple background transfer sample app from apple ([Here's a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html)!)

When I try to profile it with xcode, it tells me there is a leak with OS_dispatch_semaphore. And points me to the leaking code line:

```
    self.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on? and how to fix it.

Comment: Which Instruments template are you using?

Comment: memory leak template.   Update: looks like apple fixed it after i upgrade ios to 7.0.3

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in my code.

Comment: did you upgrade ur ios? what version is it? I dont see it happening anymore